# incorrect regexp work for htaccess rule

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Here is the original url

```
/toolkit/families-of-schools/start/ash-green-school-cv7-9ah
```

and rules in htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 
RewriteRule ^/index.php/toolkit/families-of-schools/start/(.+?)$ /index.php/toolkit/families-of-schools/start?school=$1 [L]
```

I expect `school=ash-green-school-cv7-9ah` result but instead getting

```
[school] => ash-green-school-cv7-9ah/families-of-schools/start/ash-green-school-cv7-9ah
```

What is wrong in my regexp?

Comment: Seems to me the second rule isn't applied to the output of the first rule. Maybe try to remove the `/index.php` from the second rule?

Comment: 2nd rule must never work because RewriteRule does not receive leading slash